# Where is data stored in hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, html, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I am interested to know where is local data stored in Android devices when we use one of the following approaches to save our data locally?

- localStorage
- IndexedDB
- WebSQL

Is they save in Android folder where other apps data has been saved or another places?!

Comment: It is stored in application's internal storage.

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq application's internal storage? can you explain me more or links or resources to read more? Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. you can find it in your device's internal storage>Android>Data>your app package folder>file>.